# React Native receiving BLE notifications in background

Tags: android, react-native, bluetooth-lowenergy

I am currently working on a prototype trying to listen to bluetooth LE notification while in background mode.

I am using this library https://github.com/innoveit/react-native-ble-manager to interact with BLE devices. The idea is to be able to register to a BLE service on a peripheral and get notified on characteristic changes while in background.

```
const deviceId = '8A:B0:C3:BA:11:55';
const service = '0ce0';
const characteristic = '0ce2';    

componentDidMount() {
  BleManager.start({
    showAlert: false
  });
}

onButtonPress() {
    BleManager.connect(deviceId).then(() => {
        BleManager.retrieveServices(deviceId).then(() => {
            BleManager.startNotification(deviceId, service, characteristic);
        });
    });
}

handleUpdateValueForCharacteristic(data) {
    console.log('characteristic update', data);
}

this.handlerUpdate = bleManagerEmitter.addListener(
    'BleManagerDidUpdateValueForCharacteristic',
    this.handleUpdateValueForCharacteristic
);
```

From my understanding, with this code, every time the characteristic change on the BLE device, the app will get notified even in background mode and `handleUpdateValueForCharacteristic` will be triggered.

Is is possible to have multiple app listening to the same service and characteristic on the same BLE device?

Will all these work while background and sleep mode?